# Is it possible to prepare a 0.1 N solution of HCl and methanol?

Tags: aqueous-solution, solutions

In my lab guide I read: "Use a $\pu{0.1 N}$ solution of methanol-chloridic acid $(9:1)$ for the anthocyanin extraction", so I tried to calculate the volume of $\ce{CH3OH}$ and $\ce{HCl}$ to prepare it, but I don't know how to do it. I mean, if I push one mole of $\ce{CH3OH}$ and one mole of $\ce{HCl}$ in $\pu{1 liter}$ of water, do I make a $\pu{2 molar}$ solution?

Comment: What about 9 volumes of CH3OH  + 1 volume of 1 M HCl, giving 0.1 M HCl in ( approximately ) 90% (v/v) MeOH ? BTW, I have not ever seen the term chloridic acid.

Comment: You mean, a 1 M solution of CH3OH?

Comment: Why,  I have said 1 M HCl.

Comment: So, can I use 2 or 3 M solution of CH3OH? The solution ever going to be 0.1 .  Also, I think this is a very good answer.

Comment: I doubt they consider CH3OH molarity. In my understanding, the target is to have 0.1 M HCl in 90% CH3OH.(approx.)

Comment: Furthermore, if you dissolve 1 mole CH3OH and 1 mole HCl in one liter water, you don't obtained a 2 molar solution. You obtained a solution which is about 1 molar in HCl and 1 molar in CH3OH. I say "about", because the final volume may be bigger than 1 litre. To be sure to get a solution which is 1 molar in HCl and 1 molar in CH3OH, you should dissolve 1 mole HCl and 1 mole CH3OH in a 1 liter flask, half filled with water, and afterwards, add enough water to get exactly one liter.

Comment: Of course, mixing acids and solvents may be an ES&H issue depending on jurisdiction (it is explicitly not allowed where I work).

Answer (score 1):

Of course there are such solutions.  Take, as an example, Sigma-Alrich's offer of methanolic solution of HCl (3 mol/L, e.g. [here](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/supelco/40104u?lang=en&region=US)), or the dry ones in diethyl ether (e.g., 2 mol/L [here](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/sigald/455180?lang=en&region=US)), in cyclopentyl methyl ether (e.g., [here](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/705551?lang=en&region=US)), or in 1,4-dioxane (e.g. 4 mol/L, [here](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/sigald/345547?lang=en&region=US)).